# WindowsAzure: Remote Desktop, what can I do?

Tags: windows, debugging, azure, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm connected to one of my WebRole instances. But what can I do now? I startet the Server Manager and navigated to Roles -> WebServer -> RD00123..., but what I see seems not to be the active instance. When I click on "Browse WebSite" I don't see the deployed site even I can't see or edit for instance the configured rewrite rules (defined in the web.config).

It's also funny that the inetpub is on systemdrive D (d:\inetpub\wwwroot) but the deployed (editable) files are on E (e:\approot). I'm wondering how this comes togehter.

Ok the things I want to know are:

1. How can I launch the unique instance version of the web role (I can't find an IP or port)?
2. How can I assume temporary debug changes in the web.config?
3. How can I restore the deployed version of the instance?

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't believe you can. This is managed by the Azure Fabric controller. The most you can do is force an individual instance (the one you've RDP'd into) to reboot/restart.
2) Yes. But they won't be reverted unless the VM is recycled, so be prepared to back them out yourself. This is a good use of RDP
3) Not directly. Again, this is controlled by the Azure Fabric controller. But you could put the original bits you had back into the VM manually.

I'm not sure I understand the questions regarding server manager, but I can answer the question about where things live. The "base" Windows Azure VM image is the root drive where you see INetPub at. The application is deployed to a seperate VHD (thus its presence on another drive). If you request local storage, that will come from yet another virtual drive. This is just how the Azure Fabric manages the application deployments. Properly constructed, the roles of course won't care where things live.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Does that mean, that the only way to do testing on a live instance is to edit the files in e:\approot, with the disadvantage the changes appear randomly on the live site, because of the other instances which have the old stettings? This sounds not very effective for me. Furthermore I couldn't recognize any differences after editing the web.config, is this file cached somewhere or do I need to restart something?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? For testing changes, you can either use the "staging" area of a service which is ideal for smoke testing changes before making them public. Or, if you need an entirely seperate environment silo, stand them up as a seperate service(s).

Comment: The problem is, that the behavior of the deployed application sometimes is different from the local evironment. If something brokes in production area it's not easy to debug because a new deployment needs 30-45min (staging or prod.). Thats why I want to try the stettings changes live.

Comment: Ah. In that case, you could try to do it but the challenge will be having a way to easily retrieve the new files/bits so that you can place them into the VM. Blob storage seems like a decent middle ground, but you'll likely want a light-weight client that has no external dependencies. Something you should be able to cobble together in about 10 minutes and include as part of your deployment package.